# Installing blpapi with environment.yml via pip install

Tags: python, pip, environment, bloomberg

Installing blpapi with environment.yml via pip install

I want to pip install the blpapi in an environment.yml using --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple blpapi (as can be found on https://www.bloomberg.com. However, the installation fails, using `conda env create -f environment.yml`, if I specify the yaml file as follows:

```
name: environment
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python = 3.9.12
  - pip:
      - --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple blpapi
      - greenlet==2.0.1
      - pyutil==3.3.0
```

Giving the following error in my Anaconda Prompt:

```
Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement greenlet==2.0.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for greenlet==2.0.1

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

The installation now fails for `greenlet`, but I could replace this with any other package. Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried it with `--extra-index-url`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller the anaconda prompt doesn't crash now, but the installation of the `blpapi` still fails unfortunately

Comment: I wouldn't use the https. I would use conda install -c conda-forge blpapi . When I first started working with blpapi I used the https and I could never get it to work.